# New to Ubuntu (using v2020.4.1)

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I finished installing Ubuntu, and I have a few questions:

1. How do I clear out my Hard Drive (not SSD)
2. How do I set my Hard Drive to my main drive for downloading things (desktop, apt, etc)? I have a small SSD for the soul purpose of a fast boot, but I don't want to waste the small amount (128GB) that I have.
3. How do I move the task bar to the bottom of my screen?

Comment: Thanks! I understood the .04, but just forgot to put it like that. I wrote a new topic because I am terrible at keywords, and finding what I need.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "clear out"? You want to delete all files and folders?

Answer (score 1):

About 3: How do I move the task bar to the bottom of my screen?

Click on "Show Applications" (the 9 little dots in a square). Type "Settings" and open this. Go to tab "Appearance". In the section about Dock select the "Position on screen" to your desired position.